# microsoft xml excel - row formatting

Tags: xml, excel, coldfusion-8

I am using Microsoft XML Excel with ColdFusion to display my query results on Excel sheet. I am using multiple worksheets. I see there is a border style property available. is there a way I can set background color for rows and other styles. I don't see good documentation on how to do all these.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See [XML in Excel and the Spreadsheet Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140062%28v=office.10%29.aspx) for the full documentation. But it often helps to just create a spreadsheet, save it as *.xml and review the output. Example:

```
... 
<Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="s23">
   <Interior ss:Color="#800080" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s24">
   <Interior ss:Color="#0000FF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="3" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1">
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">apple</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">orange</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
  ...
```