# How to set a cell color with XmlTextWriter

Tags: c#, excel, xmltextwriter

My program generates an Excel file using XmlTextWriter. I cannot find how exactly I could set colors of some cells (or even rows).

Here is some of my code:

```
    public static void CreateCell(XmlTextWriter w, object value)
    {
        w.WriteStartElement("Cell");
        w.WriteStartElement("Data");
        w.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Type", null, "String");

        w.WriteString(value.ToString());
        w.WriteEndElement();
        w.WriteEndElement();  
    }
```

Comment: Showing how desired XML should look like will make *this* question better. If you don't know how XML should look like you may want to rewrite the question or ask new one.

Comment: As I wrote, the result is an excel file. And the file is generated fine, I just need to be able to color some cells. It may be either background or foreground color, it does not matter. I don't know how the xml would look. But I am not sure it should be a separate question, as I am interested in the end result, i.e. color of a cell.

Comment: So go into Excel, create a cell with a color, and then output to XML. Examine the generated XML to see what the cell coloring looks like and then duplicate that in your code.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6670144/56778

Comment: Thank you Jim. If you make your advice an Answer, I would mark it as such.